# Optimum development framework for browser based deploy anywhere CRUD enterprise app?

Tags: browser, frameworks, enterprise, saas

What framework/language would you choose if you were starting a new development project with the following requirements? (I know that these are probably unrealistically ambitious, but I am hoping to understand the latest thinking and to at least get pointed in the right direction).

Must haves:
Browser based client.
Robust
Server deployable on Windows or Linux.
Depoyable as an SAAS service.
Good protection of IP.
Can create multilingual apps.
Long term future stability of language/framework (>10 years).
Needs to be able to upload and handle images, CAD files etc.

Nice to haves:
Easy to find good, low cost developers.
Easy/efficient to program.
Low deployment cost.
Server deployable on Windows or Linux for rare single-user standalone installations.
Open source.

Many thanks,
Michael

Comment: Must also offer powerful reporting, with downloadable PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd sugest Ruby on Rails, Django or the Play framework.

Comment: For an SAAS only system, I agree. But as far as I know, RoR can't protect IP effectively and can't create really well controlled/formatted pdf documents without Prince, the US$3,000 per server. This makes it unsuitable & uneconomical for other types of deployment.

Comment: Regarding pdfs: http://jimneath.org/2009/02/16/creating-pdf-documents-in-ruby-on-rails.html . What do you mean when talking about "protecting the IP"?

Comment: As far as I know, Prince is certainly the tool to produce perfect PDFs. But it costs $3,000 per server. IP = intellectual property. There is no easy way to prevent a Rails app deployed to customers from being stolen/pirated because the code can't be compiled.

Comment: Play framework looks interesting. Thanks. Is it very new and unproven? Does it have a report designer that can generate sophisticated pdf reports?

Comment: I've been a little disconnected from the Java world lately, though, I know that Play! is currently being used to develop Rails-like applications in Java and I've been reading good things about it. I do not know if it ships with any pdf generator or so, though, I know that since it is written in Java, you are then able to use any Java library to generate your reports. I've once used JasperReports for this task and it was OK, though I suppose that there may be other options to generate pdfs in Java.